# d3 force map renders the links incorrectly after re-render

Tags: d3.js

I have made an org hierarchy chart using react and Force layout. Org object has a user and defines user's relationship with others at work - like boss, coworkers, subordinates. A new person can be dynamically added in the org map which re-renders the map with new information.

However, after re-render, the map displays the links and relation text incorrectly. Even the names on the nodes get incorrectly assigned even though the data associated with node is correct. With debugging, I found that links, nodes and linklabels objects - all are correct. But the enter and exit seems a little funky and could be the source of the problem.

I have a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/warpdrive/aqu1h7zr/1/) to simulate the bug.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/warpdrive/aqu1h7zr/1/) initially renders an org map with four nodes. Joe is the user and he has a boss John, coworker Shelley, and subordinate Maria.

I have created a button to simulate dynamic adding of a new person. Clicking the button will add (data is hard coded for bug simulation) Kelly as co-worker to Maria and re-render the map. You will notice that after the render, all the links and labels are incorrect. However, when I look at the data associated with nodes in debug mode, it's correct.

I have spent a lot of time trying to figure this out but can't seem to catch the bug.

The jsfiddle is written in react. If you are not familiar with react, please ignore the react code and just focus on d3 code.

The jsfiddle code is pasted here:

Javascript:

```
const ForceMap = React.createClass({
  propTypes: {
   data: React.PropTypes.object,
     width: React.PropTypes.number,
     height: React.PropTypes.number
  },


  componentDidMount(){

    let {width,height} = this.props;

    this.forceLayout = d3.layout.force()
                         .linkDistance(100)
                         .charge(-400)
                         .gravity(.02)
                         .size([width, height])

    this.svg = d3.select("#graph")
                .append("svg")
                  .attr({id:'#org-map',width:width,height:height,backgroundColor:'white'})


    let container = this.svg.append("g").attr('class','container');
    let rect = container.append("rect")
                           .attr({width:width,height:height})
                           .style({fill:"white","pointer-events":"all"})


    this.org = this.props.data;
    this.org.x = width / 2;
    this.org.y = height / 2;
    this.org.fixed = true;

    console.log('Initial Org:',this.org);

    this.d3render(this.org);

  }, //componentDidMount

  d3render(org) {

    let container = d3.selectAll('g.container')  
    let nodes = this.flatten(org);
    let links = d3.layout.tree().links(nodes);

    let force = this.forceLayout.on("tick", tick);

    force.nodes(nodes)       // Restart the force layout.
         .links(links)
         .start();

    debugger;

    // Links line that connects two org members together
    let link = container.selectAll(".link").data(links);
    link.exit().remove()
    link.enter().append("line")
                  .attr('class',"link")
                  .attr('id', (d)=> d.source.name + '-' +d.target.name)

    console.log('link:',link);

    //Relationship label for every link
    let linkLabel =  container.selectAll(".linklabelholder").data(links);
    linkLabel.exit().remove();
    linkLabel.enter()
             .append("g")
               .attr("class", "linklabelholder")
               .attr('id', (d) => `linklabel-${d.source.name}-${d.target.name}`)
            .append("text")
               .attr({dx:1, dy: ".35em", "text-anchor": "middle"})
               .text((d) => d.target.relation)
               .style("font-size",12);

     console.log('link Labels: ',linkLabel);

    // Update nodes. Each node represents one person
    let node = container.selectAll(".node").data(nodes);
    node.exit().remove();
    let nodeEnter = node.enter()
                        .append("g")
                          .attr("class", "node")
                          .attr('id', (d) => `node-${d.name}`)

      nodeEnter.append('circle')
                  .attr('r',25)
                  .attr('id',(d) => d.name)
                  .style('fill', 'steelblue')                       

      nodeEnter.append("text")
                  .attr("dy", ".35em")
                  .text((d) => d.name)
                  .attr('id', (d) => d.name)
                  .style("font-size",12);

        console.log('Nodes: ',node);

    function tick() {
      node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x = Math.max(25, Math.min(475, d.x)); })
           .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y = Math.max(25, Math.min(275, d.y)); });

      link.attr("x1", (d) => d.source.x)
          .attr("y1", (d) => d.source.y)
          .attr("x2", (d) => d.target.x)
          .attr("y2", (d) => d.target.y)

      linkLabel.attr("transform", (d) => `translate(${(d.source.x+d.target.x)/2},${(d.source.y+d.target.y)/2})`);
      node.attr("transform", (d) => `translate(${d.x},${d.y})`)

    } //tick

  }, //d3 render



  addNewPerson() {

    let newPerson = {_id: "5",name: 'Kelly' ,relation:'coworker'};
        let addTo =  {_id:"4", name: "Maria"};

    add(this.org);

    console.log('RE-RENDER AFTER ADDING NEW PERSON');
    console.log('Org after addding new person: ', this.org);

    this.d3render(this.org);

    function add(node) {
    if (node.children) node.children.forEach(add);
      if (node._id === addTo._id) {
        if (!node.children) node.children = [];
          node.children.push(newPerson);
       }
    }
  },

 flatten(org) {
  var nodes = [], i = 0;
    recurse(org);
    return nodes;

  function recurse(node) {
    if (node.children) node.children.forEach(recurse);
    if (!node.id) node.id = ++i;
    nodes.push(node);
  }

}, //flatten

render() {
    return (
         <div>
      <div  id="graph"></div>
            <button className='btnClass' onClick={this.addNewPerson}  type="submit">Add new person
   </button>

</div>
    );
  },


});

var user = {
              name: 'Joe',
              _id: "1",
              children:[
                {_id:"2", name: "John", relation:"boss"},
                { _id:"3", name: "Shelley", relation:"coworker"},
                {_id:"4", name: "Maria", relation:"subordinate"}
              ]
        }

ReactDOM.render(
  <ForceMap
    data={user}
    width={500}
    height={300}
    />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need *key functions* for your selections to make anything other than simple datum-element binding work properly, otherwise they just replace/overwrite each other based on index:
https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#data

In this case, these will work:

```
let link = container.selectAll(".link").data(links, function(d) { return d.source_id+"-"+d.target._id+"-"+d.target.relation; });

...

let linkLabel =  container.selectAll(".linklabelholder").data(links, function(d) {
    return d.source._id+"-"+d.target._id+"-"+d.target.relation;
});

...

let node = container.selectAll(".node").data(nodes, function(d) { return d._id; });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/aqu1h7zr/3/

As for why new links overwrite nodes it's because elements are drawn in the order they are encountered in the dom. Your new links are added in the dom after your old nodes so they're drawn on top. To get round this add nodes and links to separate 'g' elements (I haven't done this in the updated fiddle), so that all links are drawn first

e.g. not

```
<old links>
<old nodes>
<new links>
<new nodes>
```

but

```
<g>
<old links>
<new links>
</g>
<g>
<old nodes>
<new nodes>
</g>
```

Comment: The above solution is perfect. I added a g group for links, as you suggested, and that solves the problem of link being drawn over the node. The jsfiddle for the latest version is here - [Force Org map](https://jsfiddle.net/warpdrive/kbo2ru8z/)